# Where to store sensitive environment variables with Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, netlify, vuejs3

According to the Vue docs, I can store environment variables in .env files and they are loaded automatically. This works fine but this page says to not store any sensitive ENV variables in these files since they are bundled with the build.

> WARNING
>
> Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your app!
>
> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can
> view them by inspecting your app's files.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

So, if I am developing a webapp that talks to an API that requires an ID and a secret to be sent in order to get a token, where am I supposed to store these ENV variables (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)?

Locally I have an .env.local file that contains these values and I'm also defining them in the Netlify env variables.

Comment: Cookies, Files, Local Storage, Browser Storage, Memory.  Take your pick.  This is a very application specific thing and no one thing is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Anything secret should be stored only on your server. It should never be part of your Vue app source code no matter how well you think you've hidden it, or encrypted it.

Generally speaking, you should have the user send their username/password, create a token on the server (look into JSON Web Tokens for a lightweight approach) and then either (1) Set it as an HttpOnly cookie (one that javascript cannot touch) or store it in localStorage on the client and set it as a common header in axios (using headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' } is fairly common.

Now, the client should be sending back that JWT with every request. So on your server, you can check the JWT is valid, and if so, send back the data requested.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have a server. This app was frontend only and it communicates directly with an API I don't own. This API requires that I send my ID and secret so I can get a JWT token. My question is: in this (serverless) case, how do I deal with these ID and secret variables?

Comment: In that case, your easiest option may be to investigate launching the app from the command line using an environment variable (or investigate dotenv if you’re using Node. And then you can access the variable in-app  using process.env.VAR. That should provide a measure of protection in theory.

Comment: I am using process.env.VAR and setting the variables in Netlify's ENV variables section. Is it safe?

Comment: Your problem is that anything that goes to your frontend is observable. All a person would have to do is inspect the Network tab for any requests to the API and the token would be there in the header or body of the request. This is why typically, you have your own server act as a middleman for any API requests that use a token you want to keep private.

Comment: So if I want to build a simple app to display my skills in a portfolio, I always have to host a server somewhere to protect my code?

Comment: Everything vue does, it does in the browser. There is basically no code running on the server. So if you want to query an API, you have to do it in the browser. If the browser has to do it, it needs to know the credentials for that API. To answer your question: Yes, if you want to protect something (like API credentials), you have to write server-side code.